# Why is this array out of bounds?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] deck = {"1♥","2♥","3♥","4♥","5♥","6♥","7♥","8♥","9♥","10♥","11♥","12♥","13♥",
                     "1♦","2♦","3♦","4♦","5♦","6♦","7♦","8♦","9♦","10♦","11♦","12♦","13♦",
                     "1♣","2♣","3♣","4♣","5♣","6♣","7♣","8♣","9♣","10♣","11♣","12♣","13♣",
                     "1♠","2♠","3♠","4♠","5♠","6♠","7♠","8♠","9♠","10♠","11♠","12♠","13♠"};

        string[] player = new string[26];
        string[] computer = new string[26];

        deck = Shuffle(deck);

        foreach (string d in deck)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(deck.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            player[i] = deck[i];
            Console.WriteLine(player[i]);
        }

        for (int j = 26; j < 52; j++)
        {
            computer[j] = deck[j];
            Console.WriteLine(computer[j]);
        }


    }

    static string[] Shuffle(string[] deck)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = deck.Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int j = r.Next(i);
            string k = deck[j];
            deck[j] = deck[i - 1];
            deck[i - 1] = k;
        }
        return deck;
    }

}
```

So what I tried doing was making a deck of cards. Then what I did was use the Shuffle method to shuffle the array and change the deck array.

It will distribute the half of the deck array to both the player and the computer (player gets first half computer gets second half). Now this is shuffled first so yeah it may seem fair.

So the line I'm getting an out of bounds error is this line:

```
computer[j] = deck[j];
```

Comment: Change to `computer[j-26] = deck[j]`

Comment: computer has a size of 26, but since arrays are 0 based, its from 0 to 25; computer[j] goes from 26 to 51, which is out of the bounds of computer.

Comment: Also, the error is pretty clear here. It's out-of-bounds. So whenever you get an error like that you should stick a breakpoint in there, trace your loop, and check the indexes are what you think they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to start indexing `computer` from 0, not 26:

```
for (int j = 26; j < 52; j++)
{
    computer[j - 26] = deck[j];
    Console.WriteLine(computer[j - 26]);
}
```

Alternatively, offset the `deck` index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    computer[i] = deck[i + 26];
    Console.WriteLine(computer[i]);
}
```

If you didn't need to print the initial cards, you could have achieved this much more concisely using LINQ:

```
player = deck.Take(26).ToArray();
computer = deck.Skip(26).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Your computer array length is `26` therefore max index is `25.` but you are trying to add element to `26.` index in that loop,that is the **reason** of the error:

```
for (int j = 26; j < 52; j++)
{
     computer[j] = deck[j];
     Console.WriteLine(computer[j]);
}
```

And the **solution** is subtract 26 from `j` in here:

```
computer[j - 26] = deck[j];
```

Also after that line:

```
Console.WriteLine(computer[j-26]);
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `computer[j-26] = deck[j];`

Answer (score 2):

Because `computer` is only length `26`, however, the `j` starts at `26` and goes up to `52`.

You need to use an offset of `26` when indexing `computer`,

```
for (int j = 26; j < 52; j++)
{
    computer[j - 26] = deck[j];

    Console.WriteLine(computer[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, you're index is correct for `deck` since it is large enough. However, `computer` is only 26 elements long. Your `i` starts at 26, which is beyond the end of `computer`. You'll need to adjust one way or the other for the two arrays, see below

```
for (int j = 26; j < 52; j++)
{
    computer[j-26] = deck[j];
    //        ^ <-adjust for smaller array
    Console.WriteLine(computer[j]);
}
```